# route http and ssh traffic normally, everything else via vpn tunnel

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing

I've read quite a bit and am close, I feel, and I'm pulling my hair out ... **please** help!

I have an OpenVPN cliend whose server sets local routes and also changes the default gw (I know I can prevent that with --route-nopull). I'd like to have all outgoing http and ssh traffic via the local gw, and everything else via the vpn.

- Local IP is 192.168.1.6/24, gw 192.168.1.1.
- OpenVPN local IP is 10.102.1.6/32, gw 192.168.1.5
- OpenVPN server is at {OPENVPN_SERVER_IP}

Here's the route table after openvpn connection:

```
# ip route show table main
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.102.1.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
10.102.1.1 via 10.102.1.5 dev tun0 
10.102.1.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.102.1.6 
{OPENVPN_SERVER_IP} via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.102.1.5 dev tun0 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.6  metric 1
```

This makes all packets go via to the VPN tunnel except those destined for 192.168.1.0/24.

Doing `wget -qO- http://echoip.org` shows the vpn server's address, as expected, the packets have 10.102.1.6 as source address (the vpn local ip), and are routed via `tun0` ... as reported by `tcpdump -i tun0` (`tcpdump -i eth0` sees none of this traffic).

What I tried was:

- create a 2nd routing table holding the 192.168.1.6/24 routing info (copied from the `main` table above)
- add an `iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING` rule to mark packets destined for port 80
- add an `ip rule` to match on the mangled packet and point it to the 2nd routing table
- add an ip rule for `to 192.168.1.6` and `from 192.168.1.6` to point to the 2nd routing table (though this is superfluous)
- changed the ipv4 filter validation to none in `net.ipv4.conf.tun0.rp_filter=0` and `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0`

I also tried an `iptables mangle output` rule, `iptables nat prerouting` rule. It still fails and I'm not sure what I'm missing:

- `iptables mangle prerouting`: packet still goes via vpn
- `iptables mangle output`: packet times out

Is it not the case that to achieve what I want, then when doing `wget http://echoip.org` I should change the packet's source address to 192.168.1.6 before routing it off? But if I do that, the response from the http server would be routed back to 192.168.1.6 and `wget` would not see it as it is still bound to `tun0` (the vpn interface)?

Can a kind soul please help? What commands would you execute after the openvpn connects to achieve what I want?

Looking forward to hair regrowth ...

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0/1 via 10.102.1.5 dev tun0` This is your issue.

0.0.0.0/1 is an insanely large IP range (0.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255) and it's the first entry in your routing table so any IP address that falls into that range will be forced to route down `tun0` . The range is so large that it encompasses a major portion of the routable IP space on the internet. So echoip.org, which for me, resolves to 69.163.172.52 is contained within 0.0.0.0/1 (0.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255).

To see if I'm correct try a wget to http://serverfault.com, which for me resolves to 198.252.206.16, and see if it goes out eth0. It should because it falls outside of (0.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255).

In general I usually make my tun0 IP space a specific as possible. `10.102.0.0/16 via 10.102.1.5` for example.

Unless your goal is to route all your internet traffic through a specific egress point for security/monitoring reasons I would try to narrow down your tunnel IP space.